# How to say "the game demands a high-characteristic device"?

Tags: phrases

I want to highlight for users that a certain game demands devices with high resources.

Could you please tell me how would native speakers say it?

Doesn't my variant in the title sound weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common term for a powerful gaming computer would be **[high-end PC](https://www.google.com/search?q=high-end%20computer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=H5NmVsjiNMGjsgH0uaKQDw)**.

> high-end goods and services are more expensive and more advanced than other similar goods and services

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/high-end))

So you could say:

> *The game requires a high-end PC*

If you need to convey some negative connotations, try **resource hog**:

> *The game is a resource hog*

Answer (score 0):

resource-hungry (as an option)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would be better if you could include any reference/research to support your answer. I would advise you to visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).